# Express - How to disable layout for a given route?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to return a plain javascript if a user access to a given route inside my app. I want to give users the oportunity to include scripts from my site inside theirs, like
this:

```
<script src="MY_DOMAIN/foo">
```

If I write:

```
app.get('/foo', function (req,res) {
  res.end("document.write('<p>Hello</p>'");
});
```

The returned javascript includes all the layout so the client browser can't handle it.

Ahy idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does `req.write("document.write('<p>Hello</p>'"); res.end();` work?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies but it still not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the content type.

```
app.get('/foo', function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/javascript'
    });

    res.end("document.write('<p>Hello</p>'");
});
```